# Node: git log between tags

Tags: git, node.js, gruntjs

With git you can get a pretty log of messages between two tags.

```
git log --pretty=oneline tagA...tagB
```

I've been using a Ruby Git Library that let me do the same thing with:

```
git = Git.open(".")
logs = git.log.between tagA, tagB
```

But I'm now trying to rewrite to something more compatible with Grunt and trying to find a decent way to do this with node. Right now the only way I can think of is making node interact with the terminal and get the output, but I don't think that would be a good way to do it.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You already use a ruby git wrapper, have you considered looking for a node/js one?  These two look halfway decent, and there may be more out there: http://www.nodegit.org, https://github.com/sentientwaffle/gift

Comment: I can't find a between method in neither of those....

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm creating a tool just for my own use, I can afford to use synchronous shell, so this is what I ended up doing, because all the node git wrappers lack documentation a bit *( don't bash me, I've seen better docs... )* and are a bit overweight for my needs.

Using [execSync](https://github.com/mgutz/execSync)

```
$shell = require("execSync")
result = $shell.exec "cd tmp/demo_git/ && git log --pretty=oneline #{from_tag}..#{to_tag}"
```

**IMPORTANT:** This is not a solution for server or an app! Doing this is okay only if you're writing a deployment app or something along those lines.